# Javascript img change statement fires too early

Tags: javascript, responsivevoice

I'm making a simulator of the Smoke and Carbon Monoxide Alarm Nest Protect, by Nest. But when I press the button (click) the inner ring doesn't turn blue as it's supposed to. It speaks, as I used ResponsiveVoice, but it just doesn't light up! Here's my (unfinished) code.

```
<script src="http://code.responsivevoice.org/responsivevoice.js"></script>    
<script>
function delay(millis)  {
    var date = new Date();
    var curDate = null;
    do { curDate = new Date(); }
    while(curDate-date < millis);
}
function press() {
    document.getElementById("unit").src = "assets/img/blue.jpg";
    delay(500);
    responsiveVoice.speak("Ready. In the Living Room. Press to test.");
    delay(500);
    document.getElementById("unit").src = "assets/img/idle.jpg";


}
</script>
```

Comment: You should really consider using `setTimeout` instead of a hard delay since JavaScript runs on a single thread, and if JavaScript execution is stuck in a while loop, the page will freeze.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try this:

```
function delay(millis, action)  {
    setTimeout(action, millis);
}

function press () {
    document.getElementById("unit").src = "assets/img/blue.jpg";
    delay(500,
        function () {
            responsiveVoice.speak("Ready. In the Living Room. Press to test.");
        }
    );
    delay(1000,
        function () {
            document.getElementById("unit").src = "assets/img/idle.jpg";
        }
    );
}
```

It's better to use setTimeout, or setInterval since most browsers use a single thread for javascript your current function will make the page unresponsive while it waits. This allows you to do other stuff asynchronously.

Comment: It worked! Had to change it to 5 seconds, but it worked! Thanks a lot man!

Comment: No problem! Happy to help!

Comment: @Gargano hey if you felt this answer solved your problem and helped would mind accepting it as the answer? Trying to earn rep points for privileges! Thanks!